# MVC3 Data in model set to null when posting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post, razor, model, null

I have a view right now where the model is a list of models that get passed into a partial view and displayed as a list on the page. The partial view has a form that, when submitted, should send the Model back to the controller where it can redirect the model to a page for editing its properties. However, one of the data members of the model is set to null after posting and I can't figure out why. Here's the code I'm using that affects this part of the program:

The Model

```
public class ViewEntryModel
{
    #region properties

    public long ActivityID { get; set; }
    public Activity ActivityModel { get; set; }
    public string ActivityType { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string ActivityName { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    #endregion

}
```

In the main View

```
<ul id="all_entries">
@foreach (var entry in Model)
{
    <div id="@String.Format("entry{0}", entry.ActivityID)">@Html.Partial("UserEntryRow", entry)</div>
}
```

In the Partial View

```
@model Web.Models.ViewEntryModel
```

```
<div class="entryInformation">
    <div class="left">
        <span>@Model.Date.Month/@Model.Date.Day/@Model.Date.Year</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        @using(Html.BeginForm("EditEntry", "UserEntry", Model))
        { 
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" /> 
        } <a>delete</a>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        @if (Model.ActivityType.Equals("Exercise"))
        { 
            <span>You completed the <strong>@Model.ActivityName</strong> exercise for <strong>@Model.Answer</strong>.</span>
        }
        else if (Model.ActivityType.Equals("Question"))
        { 
            <span>You answered <strong>@Model.ActivityName</strong> with <strong>@Model.Answer</strong>.</span>
        }
        else if (Model.ActivityType.Equals("Nutrition"))
        { 
            <span>You ate <strong>@Model.Answer</strong> servings of <strong>@Model.ActivityName</strong>.</span>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

The Controller method it's posting to

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
    public ActionResult EditEntry(ViewEntryModel model)
    {
        if (model.ActivityType.Equals("Exercise"))
        {
            ExerciseActivity exerciseActivity = (ExerciseActivity)model.ActivityModel;
            return RedirectToAction("LogPastExerciseActivity", "UserDashboard", exerciseActivity);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

When it posts, model.ActivityModel is null, even though when debugging it was correctly set inside the view. Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: One way to test what's getting posted back is to replace the ViewEntryModel model with FormCollection form.  This is a generic dictionary collection, so you can verify the keys being posted back to the server and make sure they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a few issues to address here.

1. `ViewEntryModel.ActivityModel` is declared as being of type `Activityl`, so the binding system will try and create it as an instance of that class. This line will therefore always fail:

   ```
   ExerciseActivity exerciseActivity = (ExerciseActivity)model.ActivityModel;
   ```
2. Seeing how you're using the `Activity` classes - is `Activity` abstract? If so, that's why the binding system is leaving it as null.
3. The partial doesn't post any of the `Activity` property's properties; try adding

   ```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Activity.Name)
   ```

   ...or something like that; whatever is appropriate for the `Activity` class.

If you want to stick with using `ActivityType` / `ActivityModel` properties as you are, you could create a custom `ValueProvider` to create `Activity` objects based on the `ActivityType` values. Alternatively, you could create dedicated `ViewEntryModel` types for each `Activity` type, and post them to different actions.

Comment: ActivityModel was just the property name; I know it's awkward but originally it was Activity Activity, which I changed in case that was screwing up MVC.

Activity is abstract, but when I fixed that and replaced it with its child class ExerciseActivity, the property value still came back null.

Comment: The binding system requires all of your model types to be public and non-abstract with a public, parameterless constructor. Does `ExerciseActivity` fit that description?