# Complex model child element does not bind (is null)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a complex model `RecruiterProfileViewModel` posted via multipart form (because a file upload can be included) to my ASP.NET MVC controller. It is complex in that it holds one custom child `CompanyOverviewViewModel` object.

Although browser debug shows the data to fill that child is being posted, `profile.CompanyOverview` is still `null` in my `RecruiterProfileController.Edit(RecruiterProfileViewModel profile)` post method.

Why, or how can I easily investigate?

Following are snippets of the:

- binding error
- posted data (a portion, captured in browser debugger)
- controller (the relevant method)
- parent model
- child model
- model debug (captured in VS at the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` point)
- HTML input attributes
- view

### Binding Error

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'MyApplication.Web.Models.RecruiterProfile.CompanyOverviewViewModel' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertSimpleType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.UnwrapPossibleArrayType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertTo(Type type, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertTo(Type type)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.ConvertProviderResult(ModelStateDictionary modelState, String modelStateKey, ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult, Type destinationType)}
```

### Posted Data

```
Request URL:http://localhost:61775/recruiterprofile/edit

Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryVKowpcCD1LxGmyfb

Request Payload:

------WebKitFormBoundaryVKowpcCD1LxGmyfb Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FirstName"

Marks

------WebKitFormBoundaryVKowpcCD1LxGmyfb Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CompanyOverview.PostalCode"

53213
```

### Controller

```
public partial class RecruiterProfileController {

    [CommunityRoles(CommunityRoles.Recruiter)]
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Edit(RecruiterProfileEditorViewModel profile) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            ActivityMonitor.Log(ActivityLogEntryTypes.EditRecruiterProfile);
            profile.Save(CurrentVisitor.Account.Recruiter);
            return RedirectToAction(MVC.Hub.Index());
        }
        else {
            return View(profile);
        }
    }
```

### Parent Model

```
public class RecruiterProfileEditorViewModel {

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Please enter your full first name")]
    [DisplayName("First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public CompanyOverviewViewModel CompanyOverview { get; set; }
```

### Child Model

```
public class CompanyOverviewViewModel {

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Postal Code")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
```

### Model Debug

```
profile.FirstName: "Marks",
profile.CompanyOverview: null
```

### HTML Inputs

```
<input class="text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-length="Please enter your full first name" data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="2" data-val-required="The First name field is required." id="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="" type="text" value="Marks">
<input class="text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Postal Code field is required." id="CompanyOverview_PostalCode" name="CompanyOverview.PostalCode" placeholder="" type="text" value="53213">
```

### View

```
@Html.DecoratedEditorFor(m => m.FirstName)
@Html.DecoratedEditorFor(m => m.CompanyOverview.Name)
```

---

Here's an unanswered incident of the same issue [MVC3 Data in model set to null when posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069496/mvc3-data-in-model-set-to-null-when-posting)

Comment: I'm currently doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651085/best-practices-for-debugging-asp-net-mvc-binding

Answer (score 0):

How about declaring `CompanyOverviewViewModel` as a separate parameter to your Action method then assign it to your `RecruiterProfileViewModel`?

```
[CommunityRoles(CommunityRoles.Recruiter)]
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(RecruiterProfileEditorViewModel profile,
                                     CompanyOverviewViewModel overview) {
    profile.CompanyOverview = overview;
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        ActivityMonitor.Log(ActivityLogEntryTypes.EditRecruiterProfile);
        profile.Save(CurrentVisitor.Account.Recruiter);
        return RedirectToAction(MVC.Hub.Index());
    }
    else {
        return View(profile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks WannaCSharp.

Good idea. I haven't tried that yet. My problem conceptually with it is that I should be able to round-trip the same model to the form view and form post. Separating them as you describe means I don't entirely let the MVC framework define the relationship between form field names object hierarchies. For the top level, I'm saying "I expect parameters and object fields to be treated identically". 

Side note: CompanyOverviewViewModel is optionally validated depending on whether any of the elements are returned. It may be hidden from the form in some display modes.

Comment: Also note that historically I've had some problems with expecting members and parameters to receive the same form naming convention from MVC in this sort of way. I think this shows up when using partial forms (of the sort I may wish to use here), but I forget.

Comment: I guess ultimately, I'll do this if I have to, but I think MVC is supposed to do (documented as doing) this and I'm just doing something wrong or experiencing a defect.

Comment: Hmm.Ithink it's because of the form field's name: `CompanyOverview.PostalCode` does not bind to the `PostalCode` property of `CompanyOverview` model because they have different names?

Comment: Can you show me your view? I think i have an idea why it isn't binding.

Comment: `@Html.DecoratedEditorFor(m => m.FirstName)` and `@Html.DecoratedEditorFor(m => m.CompanyOverview.Name)` you can see what it generated by looking at the HTTP debug/capture. I'll paste in two sample HTML fields in my original question.

Comment: @Shannon - Those are not MVC helpers, so they are custom.. I would look into those as the source of your problem.

Comment: Mystere Man: All `DecoratedEditorFor` contains is standard MVC helpers. Are you saying the generated inputs (shown above) are irregular or don't match the model? As per my prior comment, isnt what is the HTML form generated more relevant than the view used to generate it, when debugging model binding?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a typo elsewhere in the view, that I located by building MVC locally and stepping into it.

I had a `CompanyOverview.History` textarea input that I incorrectly had specified as `CompanyOverview`. The modelbinder first attempts to bind the value to a simple property rather than a complex property based on the form data submitted, not based on the target model.

This resulted in a binding error attempting to assign a string to my custom type, and the empty child model.